# datediff between 2 asymmetric column from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

how can i use date difference between two asymmetric row from same `table`?

```
select 
[endtime]
,[realtime]
from [prin]
where ([realtime] is not null) and ([endtime] is not null and) 
order by [realtime]
```

[between end date time and next start date time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXQCZ.jpg)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear and the image doesn't help.  Put sample data *and* desired results in the question, along with desired results.

Comment: On what basis do you want to do so? Unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DateDiff` function to get the difference between two dates. 
Add the `day` parameter to get the difference in days.

```
SELECT 
[endtime]
,[realtime]
,datediff (day,[endtime],lead ([realtime]) over (order by [realtime])) as days_endtime_2_next_realtime
FROM [prin]
WHERE ([realtime] is not null) 
AND ([endtime] is not null) 
ORDER BY [realtime]
```

Comment: @AT-2016, please feel free to edit and add it to the answer

Comment: @F.Kahalaj,  P.s. if you liked the answer you might want to upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #a
(
date_1 date,
date_2 date
)

insert into #a values
 ('1-10-16','2-10-16'),
 ('2-10-16','3-10-16'),
 ('3-10-16','4-10-16')

 ;with cte as
(
select 
date_1,date_2
,lead(date_2,1) over (order by date_2 ) as lead_value
from #a
where (date_1 is not null) and (date_2 is not null )  
)
select date_1,date_2,
datediff(Day,date_1,lead_value) as diffrence from cte
```

Comment: this code should calculate datediff as minute between end a job and start another job

Comment: u want minutes to be displayed..@F.Kahalaj

Comment: another time incorrect syntax near value @VenkateshRangu

Comment: date or minute is not important @VenkateshRangu

Comment: wait with out giving any sample data just i gave one idea if possible please post insert script  @F.Kahalaj

Comment: @F.Kahalaj i took some sample data and i tried can u check once